# Visual Studio Changing Project Paths to Invalid Values

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, solution

We have multiple developers running Visual Studio 2022 that occasionally run into an issue where the solution file project references are changed to an invalid path by removing the first character. It appears that this is happening when the solution itself is saved though it isn't apparent that this has happened until the solution is opened fresh and the projects are loaded, so is difficult to track exactly *when* it happens. We have had this occur on projects with entirely different groups of developers working on them, so it does not appear to be isolated to a single install of VS. It's relatively easy to fix when it happens but how can we stop this from happening in the future?

Correct value:
`Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ProjectName", "\\NetworkMachine\Folder\Folder\SolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\ProjectFile.csproj", "{AF8A3F8F-261C-4860-8E15-D3D98F5B3136}"`

Value after this occurs:
`Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ProjectName", "\NetworkMachine\Folder\Folder\SolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\ProjectFile.csproj", "{AF8A3F8F-261C-4860-8E15-D3D98F5B3136}"`